# In search of the perfect colour scheme

Tags: user-interface, coding-style, editor, user-experience

I don't know if the question suits better here or at http://ux.stackexchange.com, please advice.

I would like to know if are there studies about the *perfect colour scheme* for code editors? The combination among background/font colours, typo size, language highlights and so on, can in somehow affect your productivity?

**Please note that's not about personal preferences, but facts.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For studies try look for some ergonomy papers
2. yes color schemes affects productivity greatly

   - but its highly individual what is great for one programmer can ruin another.
   - from start of most programmers carrier is color scheme also a thing of 'been used to'.
   - I individually prefer dark background (better contrast and less intensity stress for my eyes).
   - The main idea is when you are comfortable with the look then you better perform your job.
   - In long term you have to consider your health
   - too big or small contrast will cause sight defects, headaches ...
   - the same goes for Font size my optimum is around 50-60 lines per page on 20" LCD.
   - too much lines of code to see at once makes comprehending of code harder
   - too less lines of code to see at once makes comprehending of code slow, even impossible
3. also code formating style matters greatly and is very often forgotten

   - in multi programmers projects is the main idea to have single style for whole project.
   - this makes sense but managers should also consider to group programmers with the same coding style because to use different coding style for a programmer leads to slowing down performance and also increase in code errors.
   - for example look on some questions there are many styles posted here.
   - and some are very hard to read when you not used to them